# Unable to locate package apt-get in docker container

Tags: docker, ubuntu-14.04

I'm trying to create a container in docker; it usually works just fine but i suddenly ran into a problem which i do know how to solve.

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get upgrade -y \
    apt-get install -y openssh-server && \
    mkdir /var/run/sshd

RUN echo root:root | chpasswd
EXPOSE 22
CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D"]
```

When it gets to apt-get update it throws the following errors:

- E: Unable to locate package apt-get
- E: Unable to locate package install

how is this possible if the image is being based of the standard ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: try running sudo apt-get update

Comment: You lack 2 && in your Dockerfile

Comment: Sudo was indeed the problem. Didn't know it was required. Thanks @charantej

Comment: Sudo is for giving the Admin Privileges. Is it worked for You ?

Comment: Yes; i know sudo is for admin privileges but i somewhat expected the default user within the dockercontainer to be able to use apt-get. Thanks though :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You didn't end your apt-get upgrade command with the `&&` so it tried to install the "packages" on the following line. I like to put my `&&` at the start of each line since it's easier for me to see when this happens (and makes copy/paste a little easier):

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

RUN apt-get update \
 && apt-get upgrade -y \
 && apt-get install -y \
      openssh-server \
 && mkdir /var/run/sshd

RUN echo root:root | chpasswd
EXPOSE 22
CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D"]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My question now feels like i had the biggest brainfart ever.

Answer (score 0):

This works.

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN apt-get update  -y
RUN apt-get upgrade -y
RUN apt-get install -y openssh-server
RUN mkdir /var/run/sshd

RUN echo root:root | chpasswd
EXPOSE 22
CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D"]
```

Comment: This only works once, then months later the update value will remain cached and changes to the Dockerfile may result in unexpected errors. See [the best practices](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/#/apt-get) for why this is advised against.

Comment: @BMitch 
Thanks, was not aware of it.